# How to pass an object of private member to another class's method?

Tags: c++, class, object

I have two classes called `PowerballLottery` and `PowerballTicket`. Inside the `PowerballLottery` there is a member function called `quickPick` that is supposed to pick 6 random valid ints and store them in `PowerballTicket`. 6 ints `mBall1, mBall2, mBall3, mBall4, mBall5 and mPowerball` are initialized within the `PowerballTicket` and the class `PowerballTicket` should store the value of the 6 random ints generated by `quickPick`. How do I pass an object of the 6 ints inside `PowerballTicket` to `PowerballLottery` so that quickPick can modify them?

Comment: Why don't you pass the 6 int values directly to the PowerballTicket? It should then be able to set its own members.

Comment: Please don't describe your code. Show your code. A [mcve], not your full code.

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass numbers to `quickPick()`. The function can just generate a `PowerballTicket` object and return it. You then assign the new value to the old licket object.

```
struct PowerballTicket
{
    int mBall1 = 0;
    int mBall2 = 0;
    int mBall3 = 0;
    int mBall4 = 0;
    int mBall5 = 0;
    int mPowerBall = 0;

    PowerballTicket(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5, int pb)
    : mBall1(b1),
      mBall2(b2),
      mBall3(b3),
      mBall4(b4),
      mBall5(b5),
      mPowerBall(pb)
    {
    }
};

class PowerballLottery
{
public:
    PowerballTicket quickPick()
    {
        // generate numbers
        // then create a PowerballTicket object and return it
        return PowerballTicket(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1000);
    }
};
```

When you want to change your `PowerballTicket` object you just do the following:

```
PowerballTicket ticket;
PowerballLottery lottery;

ticket = lottery.quickPick();
```

Answer (score 0):

make PowerballLottery a member of PowerballTicket

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't pass variables to other classes, tho it's possible

if you declare Lottery as a "friend" of Ticket, it can access it's members, even if they're private

look at this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class changer;

class fixed {
    friend class changer;
public:
    fixed(int x) : m_x(x) { } ;
    int get() { return m_x; };
private:
    int m_x;
};

class changer 
{
public: 
    void change(fixed& item, int new_value);
};

void changer::change(fixed& item, int new_value)
{
    item.m_x = new_value;
}


int main() {
    fixed one(1);
    changer two;

    std::cout << one.get() << "\n";
    two.change (one, 2);
    std::cout << one.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

the changer class is declared as a friend, so it can be used to change its members;

a lot easier in your case (if I unterstand what you want) is, if you add a setter function to Ticket, and call it for the generated numbers

```
PowerballTicket::setBalls(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5, int pb) 
{
    mBall1 = b1;
    mBall2 = b2;
    mBall3 = b3;
    mBall4 = b4;
    mBall5 = b5;
    mPowerball = pb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make `quickPick()` a friend function of `PowerBallTicket` so it can just directly access the 6 members and set them

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation looks like:

1. Create a struct with 6 fields, or use container (such as vector, for
   example).
2. Add public methods to `PowerballTicket` (setter/getter idioms) `void setData(const Cont &data)`, or keep container such as `std::vector<int>` and add method which will call `push_back(someint)`, and call it 6 times from `PowerballLottery`.
3. Add public method to `PowerballLottery`, which will keep pointer to `PowerballTicket` `void (PowerballTicket *pbt) {p_pbt = pbt;}` or pass it as a reference (`PowerballTicket &pbt`).
4. Then modify it: `p_pbt->setData` (`pbt.setData` if you used a reference).

   ```
   #include <cstdlib> // for rand

   struct Numbers
   {
       int field1;
       int field6;
   };

   class Ticket
   {
   public:
       void setData(Numbers num) { _num = num; } //movement semantic for C++11+
       Numbers getData() const { return _num; }
   private:
       Numbers _num;
   };

   class Lottery
   {
   public:
       void fillTicket(Ticket &ticket) {
           Numbers num;
           num.field1 = quickPick();
           num.field6 = quickPick();
           ticket.setData(num);
       }

   private:
          int quickPick() { return std::rand() % 100; }
   };
   ```

Comment: Although it's not stated in the question, I think the numbers are required to be all different.  At least, that's how lotteries normally work (selection without replacement)

Comment: use std::set<unsigned> as container, while(user_set.size() < 7) user_set.insert(quickPick());